# Make Glassfish redirect top domain to specific folder

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-3

I want my Glassfish (3.1.2) to redirect all traffic for at top domain to a specific application folder. Say my domain is `myapplication.com` and it runs in the Glassfish `localhost/myapp` folder. I have changed the DNS setting to point to my servers IP address. Later I will have the Glassfish to handle more top domains that point to specific folder on the server. At the moment the application runs under default `domain1`.

How can I redirect all web traffic (port 80) for a top domain to specific application folder on Glassfish server?

PS. I don't want to put a file (html) at the web root to handle the redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an answer after looking around in the Glassfish admin panel. I've changed the `docroot` parameter to point to the directory of choose.

Glassfish admin panel:

```
Configuration -> Virtual Server -> Server (Edit Virtual Server)
```

Parameter to edit:

```
Docroot: ${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/myapp
```

Guess you should define a new virtual server to handle more top domains. But maybe someone can answer if you should use another http-listner if you define another virtual-server or if Glassfish filter to different folder depending on `docroot` ?